# Need assistance Making my new css feature only apply to one page

Tags: php, html, css

im using KOSE Html template, i changed the opening page, so that the content doesn't display on the right when you first click onto the site, but only shows once you have click the "x" to display it.

Since i have done this it seems to have made the same effect on all of the pages, when i only want it on the Home page

this is the guide i followed,

Add the below CSS to your page:

```
#content-container{
  display:none;
}
```

For conformity, also add class="rotated to your hide-toggle-button link in your HTML:

```
<a href="index.php.html#" id="hide-toggle-button" class="rotated"><i class="icon ion-ios7-close-empty"></i></a>
```

but it changes every page, please can you help

I much appreciate it!

thanks

Comment: What you want is to have a CSS ID to only work on a page ? You can't do that. Instead, you can create a new ID only for the respective page, name it to something different so it only affects one page instead of having to edit more pages, and use the new ID you created for the page you want. Voila!

Comment: Thanks ever so much for your quick reply!, is there another way you can help me do this. as i dont really understand how to do that.

thanks so much ShowTime!

Comment: The best way is to have a class on your body tag that reflects which page you are on. Then you can always scope your css depending on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to only work in the current page add the following code in your home page `<head>` tags:

```
<style>   
#content-container{
  display:none;
}
</style>
```

The CSS priority is like this:
- External .CSS File
-- `<style>` Tag
--- Inline `style` Attribute.

This means  overwrites the stuffs written in the .CSS file for a certain page, in order to achieve what you wanted.

I hope this helped you.

Comment: Do i then remove this from the .css ?

Comment: You won't have to remove anything, just add what I typed above.

Comment: Perfect thanks, is there any other way i can contact you direct as i have one minor problem its really not a problem if its not fixable as its just a small thing thats bugging me.